# Router does not redirect inside a function

Tags: reactjs, celery

I am creating a function that tracks the status of a Celery background job.
Basically, the background job will send a JSON to the frontend with the word `PENDING` if it is not done, or `SUCCESS` if it is done.
I am checking every second if the JSON has changed by calling `setTimeout`.

However, when the function enters the else,statement, I get printed in console `console.log("redirect")` but it does **NOT** execute the code:             `return <Redirect to={{pathname: '/dashboard/'}}/>`

The routing works since I tried to redirect outside the `if-else` statement

I am not sure why it does not redirect.

```
function MyComponent() {
...
    function updateProgress(statusUrl) {
        const celeryStatus = fetch(statusUrl)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(jsonData => {checkStatus(jsonData, statusUrl)})
    }

    function checkStatus(jsonData, statusUrl) {
        if (jsonData.state === "PENDING") {
            console.log("inside pending")

            setTimeout(function() {
                updateProgress(statusUrl);
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            console.log("redirect")
            return <Redirect to={{pathname: '/dashboard/'}}/>
        }
    }
# Calling the functions
return ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning component from a function that does not render anything, Redirect component should be put inside render() method or functional component

if this is react-router

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';
```

and then, to navigate programatically

```
const history = useHistory();
if(someCondition){
   history.push('/somewhere');
}
```

Comment: Can't he just use `this.props` since the component default has history on the props object?.

Comment: Should I put this in my component or in my function inside the component?

Comment: It doesnt really matter as long as hook is called inside of component. And I'm not sure about this.props since I've never tried that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below

```
      this.props.history.push({
        pathname: '/dashboard',
      })
```